# How to reduce the time taken to launch the app in cold start

Tags: android, performance, operating-system, splash-screen, cold-start

I'm trying to optimize my app. We have launch Interstitial Ad in our app. When there is a Ad, app takes around 7-8  seconds to start the home screen. When Ad is not available, it takes 3 seconds to launch the home screen. Problem is with the `cold start`: when app is launched first time, after `installation` or `update`. The app takes around `4-5 seconds` to show my `splash screen`. I know this is because when app is launched first time, OS takes time to initialize the app and is common to most of the apps. But I have observed few apps, which takes very less time to launch the home screen and black screen can be hardly seen. I can avoid the black screen, by setting custom theme to activity. But I want to reduce the time taken between black screen and splash screen. For other launches it hardly takes 1 second between `black screen` and `splash screen`. Is there anything that can be done, to reduce the delay on first launch

Comment: which IDE are you using, and of which version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

depends on how you have organised your Home/Splash Activity and where you have defined the heavy tasks in the Activity lifecycle callbacks.

In general, test your app and see which methods take much time than others and start with optimizing them.
Try do minimum(no) work at onCreate() and onStart().
Send time consuming work to back thread.

Further you can checkout **Launch Fast** section of this 9Part post by Chet Haase. https://medium.com/google-developers/developing-for-android-iii-2efc140167fd#.7fkyvlowf

Comment: what if the oncreate is a must as I'm following third-party documentation?